# Hovers don't allow me to make a link

Tags: html, css, image, hover, overlay

I'm having some trouble with links. I tryed to make a cool looking hover effect on my images but destoyed the option to click a link. Obviosuly the problem is somewhere in the css transition part... I think the overlay "kills" it but I'm not a expert. Thank you for all your anwasers in advance.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

          <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>projects</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
        <div class="logo" >
            <img src="lg.png" alt="" width="180" height="178" class="logo"/>
        </div>


<nav> <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>  <a href="About.html"      class="transition">ABOUT</a>  <a href="Contact.html" class="transition">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
<div class="ozadje"> 
<div class="table">
<div class="vrsta">
<div class="okno">

  <div class="raste">
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
  <a href="Logofolio.html" class="transition" ></a>
  <div class="mask">
                    <h2>Logofolio</h2>
                    <p> Colection of my logos for a veriety of<br> different clients.</p>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="okno">
   <div class="raste">
   <img src="vodka.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
   <a href="Logofolio.html" class="transition" ></a>
   <div class="mask">
                    <h2>ELITE VODKA</h2>
                    <p> The idea was make a vodka design stand out from the competiotion and also give a strong symbolistic concept. </p>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="okno">
  <div class="raste">
  <img src="tamn.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
  <a href="Logofolio.html" class="transition" ></a>
  <div class="mask">
                    <h2>PERFUME DESIGN</h2>
                    <p> A simplistic perfume design for women. Saying as much as possible, with as little as possible but still achive clarity, balance and harmony. </p>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vrsta">
<div class="okno">
  <div class="raste">
  <img src="pedall.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
  <a href="Logofolio.html" class="transition" ></a>
  <div class="mask">
                    <h2>GUITAR PEDAL</h2>
                    <p> You can have good sounding pedal that looks boring. What it you could have the best of<br> both worlds?  </p>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="okno">
  <div class="raste">
  <img src="keww.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
  <a href="Logofolio.html" class="transition" ></a>
  <div class="mask">
                    <h2>Kew Guide</h2>
                    <p> Kew garden has a ton of beautiful sites to see all year around. Don't know where to start? Grab a brochure to make your life easy. </p>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="okno">
  <div class="raste">
  <img src="moca.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
  <a href="Logofolio.html" class="transition" ></a>
  <div class="mask">
                    <h2>MOCA SHOP</h2>
                    <p> A organic coffee shop design<br> inspired by coffee.</p>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>




     <footer>copyright 2016 matic toni</footer> 
    </body>
```

```
css

@charset "utf-8";
.logo {
padding-bottom: 0.5%;
text-align: center;

}

nav {
font-family: "Proxima";
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
word-spacing: 80px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-bottom: 1%;
padding-left: 50px;
color: #000000;
}

nav:before {
border-radius: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
}

nav:before,

.table {
display: table;
margin: auto;
max-width: 600%;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

a:hover {
color: lightgray;
}

a:active {
color: black;
}

body { background-color: #F6F6F6;
   margin: 0;

}

.raste img {

display: block;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;

}
.vrsta{

overflow: hidden;
}

.okno {
display: inline-flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 10px;

}

.raste {

width: 300px;
height: 200px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
border:  solid black;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
background: black url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
border-radius: 10px;
 }
.raste .mask,.raste .content {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-radius: 10px;
}
.raste img {
display: block;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;

}
.raste h2 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: sans-serif ;  
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 17px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
 }
 .raste p {
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 12px;
 position: relative;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px 20px 20px;
 text-align: center;
 }


.raste img {
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
border-radius: 10px;

}
.raste .mask {
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
background-color: rgba(149,149,149,0.62)  ;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
border-radius: 10px;
}
.raste h2 {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
-moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
-o-transform: translateY(-100px);
-ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
transform: translateY(-100px);
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.raste p {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
-moz-transform: translateY(100px);
-o-transform: translateY(100px);
-ms-transform: translateY(100px);
transform: translateY(100px);
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.raste:hover img {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
border-radius: 10px;
}

.raste:hover .mask {
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
}
.raste:hover h2,
.raste:hover p,
.raste:hover a.info {
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
-moz-transform: translateY(0px);
-o-transform: translateY(0px);
-ms-transform: translateY(0px);
transform: translateY(0px);

}
.raste:hover p {
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
-o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
-ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.raste:hover a.info {
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
 }
```

Comment: All we need is a **minimal** demo...just enough to demo the whole problem...not the whole page.

Comment: http://www.matictoni.com/projects.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your items html like this:

```
<div class="okno">     
   <div class="raste">
       <a href="Logofolio.html" class="transition" >
          <img src="tamn.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>

          <div class="mask">
              <h2>PERFUME DESIGN</h2>
              <p> A simplistic perfume design for women. Saying as much as possible, with as little as possible but still achive clarity, balance and harmony. </p>
          </div>
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to wrap your item inner html in `<a>` tag :)

Comment: doesn't work... here's the preview http://www.matictoni.com/projects.html

Comment: @MaticToni You didn't changed the code. Just change the code like the answer and i'll check the preview again.